# How much water is needed for flour dough when making chapati

Tags: dough, indian-cuisine

This is for Indian/Pakistani chapati recipe.

How do I know if I have used the appropriate amount of water when making the dough? There is no yeast involved here. What do I do if I have added too much water?

When I made the dough for first time in life a few days ago, I tried to use 2:1 ratio of flour to water. However, all water was not used making flour have higher ratio. Quite a bit of water was left when I finished. It is hard to accurately say what % was left.

Even after leaving it for more than an hour, when I started making the chapatis, the dough was too much sticky and I think this is because of adding more water than needed.

Answer (score 2):

When making chapattis, the recipe might give a quantity of water, but it will probably also say you might not need it all. So you should add it gradually.

For example, the recipe I use says for 225g (8Oz) of flour you use 110ml of water "very approximately"  and add it gradually "until all the flour is incorporated and you have a soft, pliable dough". Then the dough rests for 15 minutes. I actually have my doubts about the conversions in this recipe, but the method is more important so it always works.

Quotes are from *The curry secret* -- Kris Dhillon

Answer (score 1):

As you know dough for chapatti is kneaded without yeast, butter it's kneaded with simple water so you need to add more water to knead it, I would recommend adding water in small quantities and knead you know when it's done when

1. it won't stick no longer to your hands
2. it's soft enough that you can insert fingers easily in the dough.

Comment: it won't stick to my hands? You mean when it is done kneeding. Is that because it does not have too much water?

Comment: when you add water to flour it becomes sticky if you knead with your hands , it means it has absorbed extra moisture and it's not too watery, it's soft enough that you can insert fingers easily in the dough. means it's not too dry.